# How to get an enemy's information?

Tags: godot

I'm a beginner and I created a code where I can get my enemy's information, but I believe it is very simple and maybe wrong, since the more information I want to get, the more lines of code will be needed.

My idea is that when I get this contact between the player and the enemy (or object), I have this informations and can use it in combat math.

Another question is that the RayCast "works", however, I don't get this information in the first contact with the enemy.

Player code:

```
func _unhandled_input(event):
for dir in inputs.keys():
    if event. is_action_pressed(dir):
        move(dir)
        
func move(dir):
    ray.cast_to = inputs[dir] * grid_size
    ray.force_raycast_update()
    if !ray.is_colliding():
        position += inputs[dir] * grid_size
            
    if ray.is_colliding():
        if "Enemy" in ray.get_collider().get_groups():
            var AC_enemy = ray.get_collider().AC
            print("Colisão com inimigo")
            print(AC_enemy)
```

In the enemy code I left only the value of the AC variable.

Thanks

Comment: Be aware that with this code it will detect when the player runs into the enemy, but not when the enemy runs into the player. Is that the issue you are trying to solve? By the way, using `is_in_group` is more efficient than searching in `get_groups`.

Comment: The enemy will not move. I want to learn how to get the enemy's information when there is contact.

Comment: Is it getting the information at the wrong time or not getting it at all? If you do `if ray.is_colliding(): prints(ray.get_collider())` what do you get? Something else to try: add `ray.force_update_transform()` before `ray.force_raycast_update()`.

Comment: In answer to your first question, the way that you're getting enemy data is fine.  You need to access the properties that belong to your enemy to perform the calculation so there needs to be lines of code to handle that somewhere.  To make it more maintainable, you could write a function to handle the collision and just pass the enemy object to the function or you could add the logic for handling/calculating the collision to the enemy class itself - it all depends on your preference and general architecture.